# Why does this not work: 'git log branchname:filepath'?

Tags: git, git-log

Why does this not work:

```
git log someBranch:path/to/myfile.txt       
echo $?  # shows 0/success but no output from git log
```

(This does work:)

```
git rev-parse someBranch:path/to/myfile.txt # this works and returns the SHA
```

Is there another way to get the log/commits relevant to a specific file on a specific branch (without checking out that branch) ?

Answer (score 1):

`git log --branches=<regex> -- <filename>`: logs all the commits that modified `filename` in the branches which name matches `regex`.

Comment: To fill in a nook, OP's syntax doesn't work  because `git log` expects tips, it does does an internal `git rev-parse` on everything before the `--`, so passing the commit:path syntax gets resolved to a SHA that `git log` then expects to be a commit..

Comment: @Nino : Can you give a concrete example? Also will it work if filename doesn't exist in the branch you're currently ON ?

Comment: I think maybe this works:
    `git log somebranch -- somefile`
    
eg:
    `git log origin/csd-test -- misc/csd-test6.sql`

Comment: @Mitch: `git log --branches=myBranch* -- README.md`
If the file name doesn't match any file, nothing is logged (but the log is successful)

Comment: Please note that `git log --branches=myBranch` will not log anything, because setting `myBranch` as the regex is equivalent to setting `myBranch/*` (cf the git-log man page: *"If pattern lacks ?, \*, or [, /\* at the end is implied."*)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work as desired is that `git log` is about *commits* while `someBranch:path/to/myfile.txt` names a *blob*.  The word "blob" is Git-speak for, roughly, "file as stored inside a commit".

To understand this completely, read through the description at the web site [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  But to just get a general feel for it, read the following:

Git is mainly about *commits*.  It's not really about *branches* after all.  This means you need to know what, exactly, a commit *is*, and what the difference is between a commit and a branch.  This gets a bit sticky because Git, and people using Git, mix together several different meanings for the word "branch".  To disentangle these two meanings for *branch*, it helps to get very specific and talk instead about each *branch name*.  But let's start with the commits.

The real name of any commit is a big ugly hash ID.  You will see these hash IDs in `git log` output:

```
$ git log
commit c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 4 14:33:27 2018 -0700

    Git 2.19-rc2

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

That `c0504...1231` thing is the actual name of the commit, and as you can see, the commit remembers its author and a time-stamp.  (There's more but we'll stop here to keep this short-ish.)

There are two main functions of a commit: the commit makes Git retain—forever, or as long as the commit continues to exist, which might as well be forever—a *complete snapshot* of everything in the repository.  Well, more precisely, the commit retains a snapshot of everything in the commit, but that seems a little redundant: the commit has what the commit has.  Still, that's the most accurate way to put it.  The reason to say it has a complete snapshot of everything is that other version control systems often store commits as *changes*, but Git stores them as whole snapshots.

The other main function of a commit is to remember its *parent*, or previous commit.  What you can't see above is that the parent of `c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231` is `e9983f8965c0875cc6727e9644c84ff1dfc99372`.  To see it directly, you can use `git cat-file -p c05048d43925ab8edcb36663752c2b4541911231`.  But `git log` will see it, and that's what matters for us here:

**After showing us one commit, `git log` moves on to show us the previous / parent commit.**  It finds the previous / parent commit using the parent's true name—its big ugly hash ID—stored in the commit.  Whenever we have the big ugly ID of a commit in our hands, we can use it to *find* the actual commit.  We generally say that this ID *points to* the commit: it lets us find it.

So, each commit points to its parent.  This makes a backwards-looking chain.  If we use single uppercase letters to stand in for big ugly hash IDs, we get something much more human-friendly, although then we'd run out of letters after just 26 or so commits (depending on the alphabet):

```
A  <-B  <-C  ...  <-H
```

With this one-letter system, it's pretty easy to find the *last* commit: we just find the last letter.  But these are standing in for the real, apparently-random (not random at all but not predictable either) hashes.  So we need to know, somehow, that `H` is the *last* hash, and this is where branch *names* come in.

**A branch name like `master` stores the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.**  Git calls this the *tip* commit of the branch.  *The name always points to the tip commit,* so we should draw it in like this:

```
A  <-B  <-C  ...  <-H   <--master
```

If we add a *new* commit to the branch, the way Git does this is to leave all the existing commits intact, without touching them at all.  It whips up some new big ugly hash ID `I` and sets `I`'s parent to `H`, and then it *changes the name* `master` so that `master` stores `I`'s hash ID instead of `H`'s:

```
A  <-B  <-C  ...  <-H  <-I   <--master
```

Now, starting at the end—using the name `master` to find `I`—we can work with commit `I`.  Commit `I` remembers `H`'s hash, so we can use it to get to `H`.  `H` remembers `G`'s hash, so we can use *that* to get to `G`, which gets us to `F`, and so on, backwards.  Eventually this leads to `B` and to `A`, and since `A` is the very first commit ever, it has *no* parent, and we can stop.

#### With all of this, we finally get to how `git log` does its job

The main task for `git log` is to *show some set of commits, starting from some starting-point* (or maybe we should call it *ending-point* since Git always works backwards).  We can start from *any* commit, as long as we have its hash ID.  But the hash IDs we have are the ones that are stored in *branch names*.

The drawings above show how the diagram looks when there's only *one* branch name.  If there are more branch names, each of those names stores a hash ID of some *tip* (rightmost, in our drawings) commit.  Each commit points to its parent as usual.  If we start drawing the internal arrows as just connecting lines to make it easier, this gives us, e.g.:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
         \
          J--K   <-- develop
```

The name `master` says *start from `I` and work backwards*.  The name `develop` says *start from `K` and work backwards*.

(Note that as we work backwards, we eventually reach commit `G`, no matter whether we start from `I` or from `K`.  This question is for your future exploration: *Which branch(es) contain commit `G`?*  We won't address that here for now.)

#### Limiting `git log`'s output

In any case, what `git log` does is start at the end, and march along the chain of commits, backwards, showing you each commit, one at a time.  In a big project, that can be a whole lot of commits.

Each commit has a complete snapshot of *all* of the files.  If you've had `path/to/myfile.txt` in the repository for a long time, there are a *lot* of copies of `path/to/myfile.txt`.  Many of them are probably exactly the same, and if so, Git gets to *share* them, to use just one copy for all the commits that have that particular version of it.  Git can do this because the committed versions are frozen: nothing can change them ever.

But if they're *the same* as each previous commit, that makes each of those commits pretty boring, from your point of view!  Why start at commit `Z` and then show `Y` and `X` and `W` and so on, if all of those commits have *the same* `path/to/myfile.txt` in them?  So this is where `git log` has the ability to *not* show commits.

You can ask `git log` to show you commits, starting from some starting (ending?) point and working backwards, but *skip showing most of them*.  You can tell it: *Show me each commit if and only if, after comparing the commit and its parent, the file `path/to/myfile.txt` is **different** in those two commits.*

That is, `git log` will start at the end—commit `Z`—and look up `Z`'s parent `Y`.  If `path/to/myfile.txt` is *the same* in `Z` and `Y`, `git log` *won't* show `Z`.  If it's different, `git log` *will* show `Z`.  Then, in any case, Git will move back to `Y`.  Now that it's working on `Y`, Git will look up `Y`'s parent `X`.  If `path/to/myfile.txt` is *the same* in `Y` and `X`, `git log` will just move on to `X`.  This goes on until you either get tired of `git log` output, or `git log` gets all the way back to the very first commit.

**To make this work, you must give `git log` the right starting (ending?) commit or commits.**  That's where `git log branchname` comes in.  The default for `git log` is to start at your *current commit*, but you want to start at some other specific commit: the tip of some branch name.  **Then you must also give `git log` the limiting file(s).**  That's where `-- path` comes in.  The path names go after `--` to separate them from branch names.  If you have a file named `master`, `git log master` will show you the commits starting from `master`, but `git log -- master` will show you the commits starting from your current commit, limited to those that changed the file `master`.

Note that it does not matter whether the file name after `--` exists: `git log` just checks to see if there's a difference in such a file between commits as it walks backwards through history.  If the file is not in both of the two commits it's comparing at any one time, that means "no change to the file".  If the file is in exactly *one* of the two commits, that means the file *did* change (was added or deleted).  If the file is in both snapshots, the file changed if and only if, well, the file changed, of course.

#### Why `git log someBranch:path/to/myfile.txt` fails should be clear now

Using `someBranch:path/to/myfile.txt` has `git log` look up the raw blob hash ID.  That's not a commit, so `git log` can't show it, and doesn't.  Then `git log` has no *commit* to start with, so it can't work backwards either.  Having no commits to show, it just does nothing, and quits.  It might make sense for `git log` to at least warn you that your starting-point (ending-point?) was not a commit at all, but it doesn't.